# Does " adjacent order of arrangement" make sence?

Tags: phrases

I want to use the phrase "adjacent order of arrangement", for example, as follows:

> The four sides of a die are numbered 2, 6, 5 and 1 in adjacent order
> of arrangement.
> [image]

I could not find this phrase on google although could find some examples of "adjacent order".  Is this phrase understandable to natives?

Comment: It's 'understandable', but is a very unnatural way to express it. The sides are adjacent (lying next) to one another; the word doesn't describe the order they are in. Anyway, a die has _six_ sides!

Comment: From any given starting face, 4 of the other 5 faces of a cube are *all* "adjacent". The only face that *isn't* adjacent is the one directly opposite (which will definitely be included in the *second* set of 4 "adjacent faces", whichever choice was made from the first set). I'm not great at maths / topology, but I think that means there are 4 x 3 x 2 = 24 different possible "adjacent order" sequences. Not a very useful concept.